# Create a vector to shoot a projectile at angle of cannon

Tags: ios, vector, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I need to set a projectile in motion doing this (Box2d):

projectileBody->SetLinearVelocity(b2Vec2(shootVector.x, shootVector.y));

I know the angle (it's the rotation angle of the cannon), and I'm sure it's simple to create shootVector given the angle but I can't figure it out. I know `tan(angle) = y/x.`

```
CGPoint shootVector = (???, ???);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming angle of the cannon is from the x axis:

```
CGPoint shootVector;
shootVector.x = velocity * cos(angle);
shootVector.y = velocity * sin(angle);
```